# How to skip the failed beans in springboot to avoid reportFailure:771 >> Application startup failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-bean

**Is there any way to skip the failure bean to avoid application startup failed.Let me explain the scenario.**

I am creating hazlecast bean on application startup.sometime hazecast server might be not alive.In that time when i am starting the springboot application hazecast  instance gets failed so that application startup also  gets failed.

**Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastInstance' 
[restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  ,  reportFailure:771 >> Application startup failed**

But My application is not only having hazecast bean ,it also has lot of beans  for various services.is there any possibilities to  skip the failed beans for application gets started??.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can mark them beans with `@Lazy` so spring will not construct them on application startup. It will construct them when you use them runtime.

please see this documentation

https://memorynotfound.com/lazy-initialize-autowired-dependencies-with-lazy-annotation/