# How to prevent fail fast on external connection failure like Redis server in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

Is there a way to prevent `spring-boot` application from failing on startup due to external connection failures? I have found [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52125485/3503019) that suggest using `@Lazy` annotation to prevent `@Configuration` beans initialisation but this solution did not work for me with `Spring Data Redis` using `Jedis` client.

Also, other solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54625186/3503019) one are specific to dependencies being used in the app. For example, `Spring Cloud` has below property to control failfast behaviour -

```
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
```

You can use [this project](https://github.com/akashsolanki/springboot-redis) that I created for my problem to reproduce by shutting down the `redis` server.

Below is how my code looks like -

```
@Lazy
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.redis.sentinel.master}")
    private String SENTINEL_MASTER;

    @Value("${spring.redis.sentinel.nodes}")
    private String SENTINEL_NODES;

    @Value("${spring.redis.security.enabled:false}")
    private boolean REDIS_SECURITY_ENABLED;

    @Value("${spring.redis.security.password:}")
    private String REDIS_PASSWORD;

    @Lazy
    @Bean // somehow this always gets initialized
    public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() { 
        // create set of sentinel nodes
        System.out.println(SENTINEL_NODES);
        Set<String> sentinelNodesSet = new HashSet<>(5);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(SENTINEL_NODES, ",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
            sentinelNodesSet.add(st.nextToken());
        RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration(SENTINEL_MASTER, sentinelNodesSet);
        if (REDIS_SECURITY_ENABLED) {
            sentinelConfig.setPassword(REDIS_PASSWORD);
        }
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig);
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Below is the exception trace -

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'stringRedisTemplate' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'stringRedisTemplate'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path
> resource [com/springboot/redisintegration/RedisConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels
> down, cannot determine where is mysentinel master is running...   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]    at
> com.springboot.redisintegration.RedisIntegrationApplication.main(RedisIntegrationApplication.java:21)
> ~[classes/:na] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path
> resource [com/springboot/redisintegration/RedisConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels
> down, cannot determine where is mysentinel master is running...   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   ... 20 common frames
> omitted Caused by:
> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: All sentinels
> down, cannot determine where is mysentinel master is running...   at
> redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.initSentinels(JedisSentinelPool.java:249)
> ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:na]     at
> redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.(JedisSentinelPool.java:154)
> ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:na]     at
> redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.(JedisSentinelPool.java:122)
> ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:na]     at
> redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.(JedisSentinelPool.java:116)
> ~[jedis-3.3.0.jar:na]     at
> org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createRedisSentinelPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:374)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:358)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(JedisConnectionFactory.java:342)
> ~[spring-data-redis-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]   ... 31 common frames
> omitted

**In short**:

1. `@Lazy` annotation works for `RedisStandaloneConfiguration` but not `RedisSentinelConfiguration`, not sure why?
2. Using `@Lazy` annotation is risky because you need to make sure all your services which are using `Redis` are loaded lazily too.
3. Looking for a solution like `spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true` provided for spring cloud.

**Update**:

I've created below Jira issue for this feature -

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-1208

Comment: what is the error you are getting @akash

Comment: @Vishrant udated the error details.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood Spring Cloud Config uses `spring-retry` and AOP (`spring-boot-starter-aop`) to configure a retry mechanism.

This process is implemented in [ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/6d53c980dbc6c8998c0223007a4f9a1215131ee1/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java).

The relevant part of the code is this:

```java
/* @ConditionalOnProperty("spring.cloud.config.fail-fast") */
@ConditionalOnClass({ Retryable.class, Aspect.class, AopAutoConfiguration.class })
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableRetry(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Import(AopAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(RetryProperties.class)
protected static class RetryConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "configServerRetryInterceptor")
  public RetryOperationsInterceptor configServerRetryInterceptor(
      RetryProperties properties) {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
        .backOffOptions(properties.getInitialInterval(),
            properties.getMultiplier(), properties.getMaxInterval())
        .maxAttempts(properties.getMaxAttempts()).build();
  }

}
```

As you can see, the basic idea is to provide a `RetryConfiguration` that handles a certain number of retries before considering the application failed.

The [documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/9cd18d2f0f66deecbd4362cfae40b3ff0b743e78/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc#config-client-retry) of Spring Cloud Client provide more information about the different properties used for configuring this mechanism. You can see the default values also in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/6d53c980dbc6c8998c0223007a4f9a1215131ee1/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/RetryProperties.java) of the `RetryProperties` class.

Please, try and include the two required dependencies, `spring-retry` and `spring-boot-starter-aop`, and the `RetryConfiguration` as a child of your main configuration, provide some reasonable defaults for the configuration properties of the retry mechanism, and see what happens.

You can push the solution to the limit and try to reconnect on a very large number of occasions, perhaps increasing the cadence between them, waiting for the server to be available.

I think that the `@Lazy` annotations will no be longer necessary and could be safely removed.

**EDIT**

Reviewing your error stack trace, one think you can also try is to disable String Boot Redis auto-configuration classes.

You can do it in your annotations:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(
  exclude = { RedisAutoConfiguration.class, RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class }
)
```

Or in your properties files:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude= \
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration, \
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
```

You can disable Redis repositories configuration with this property also:

```
spring.data.redis.repositories.enabled: false
```

Once you disable the Redis auto-configuration, you will be free to instantiate the `RedisTemplate` or the stuff you need to interact with Redis when you consider appropriate.

You can, for instance, initialize it on demand, trying to establish a connection to Redis, by initializing all the required factories, when it is actually required. You can surround with `try` and `catch` the logic required to initialize your Redis connection and only initialize the `RedisTemplate` if a connection is available, something like the following.

On one hand:

```java
public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() { 
    try {
      // create set of sentinel nodes
      System.out.println(SENTINEL_NODES);
      Set<String> sentinelNodesSet = new HashSet<>(5);
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(SENTINEL_NODES, ",");
      while (st.hasMoreTokens())
          sentinelNodesSet.add(st.nextToken());
      RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration(SENTINEL_MASTER, sentinelNodesSet);
      if (REDIS_SECURITY_ENABLED) {
          sentinelConfig.setPassword(REDIS_PASSWORD);
      }
      JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig);
      return jedisConnectionFactory;
    } catch (redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException re) {
      logger.error("Unable to initialize Redis connection factory", re);
      return null;
    }
}
```

On the other:

```java
public RedisTemplate getRedisTemplate() {
  // We can assume that both methods are defined in the same class, 
  // although it is not necessary
  final RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = this.jedisConnectionFactory();
  if (redisConnectionFactory == null) {
    return null;
  }

  final RedisTemplate redisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate(redisConnectionFactory);
  return redisTemplate;
}
```

You can use this `RedisTemplate` in the way you consider appropriate and, of course, cache and reuse it as necessary.

These methods can be defined in a service or helper class created for this task and, of course, not in your configuration classes.

Comment: @akash Could you test the proposed solution? Did it work?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I'll try this sometime today and let you know.

Comment: Nice @akash. I hope it works. Please, do not hesitate to contact me if you think I could be of any help

Comment: This solution does not work on startup. It retries the connection only when the  spring boot is completely up and when the `redis sentinels` go down after start up. It looks like a `retry` mechanism. Which is not what I'm looking for. The springboot apps should ignore the connection failures and get started.

Comment: It is ok @akash. Please, let me further investigate, I will check it out.

Comment: @akash I updated my answer with new ideas. Hope it can help you to finally solve the problem.

Comment: @akash Could you test anything of the new solutions proposed?

Comment: Thanks again. I did not try your second solution, will try sure. One question though - How do I let spring manage `Redis Configuration` after disabling `Redis Auto Configuration`?

Comment: I hope it works. The idea is that you, on demand, manage the necessary logic in order to create and free, when required, the acquired Redis resources. If you think about it, actually the only resource you actually need is a ```RedisTemplate``` with an underlying connection factory. This is what Spring needs. If it is relevant or not will depend on your actually use case: if you need to configure, for instance, a cache mechanism and Spring required this bean for it, this solution will not work. But if you are storing information in Redis with your own logic it will provide you a good solution.

Comment: Right. But frameworks are meant to reduce the boilerplate code and I don't understand why it can't be as simple as a enabling or disabling a property.

Comment: Yes, but if you think it carefully, the framework is providing you a lot and great stuff. But the framework also assumes that some assets will be always necessary for your application work properly: think, for instance, in databases of any type, ```Redis``` is your case. Also, in your use case, you are using sentinels, which is meant to provide you a high available and failover aware ```Redis``` storage: it is not a typical scenario that you could not contact this kind of resource.